# Dart sort List of Maps based on list of values

Tags: dart

I have a list of maps, and i want to sort it based on values that are in another list, here is the data list:

```
final data = [{
  'id' : 1,
},
{
  'id' : 10,
},
   
{
  'id' : 2,
},
   
   {
  'id' : 1,
},
   {
  'id' : 10,
},
   {
  'id' : 1000,
}];
```

And this is the sorting list:

```
List<int>  sortingList =  [1000,1, 6, 99];
```

I want to sort the `data` list based on the order of the ids that exists in the `sortingList`, meaning for example `1000` is in position one so i want the data that has `id == 1000` at the beginning of the list, `1` is the second element of the `sortingList` so i want all the data that has `id == 1` to be listed after the elements that has `1000` and so on. The elements that has `id` that's not in `sortingList` should be at the end of the list, the final result if i print the value `id` after sorting it should be like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      print(data[i]["id"]);
}

 1000
 1
 1
 10
 2
 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you check if it is something like this you want?

```
void main() {
  final data = [
    {'id': 1},
    {'id': 10},
    {'id': 2},
    {'id': 1},
    {'id': 10},
    {'id': 1000}
  ];

  final sortingList = [1000, 1, 6, 99];
  final sortingMap = {
    for (var i = 0; i < sortingList.length; i++) sortingList[i]: i
  };

  data.sort((a, b) {
    final aPos = sortingMap[a['id']!];
    final bPos = sortingMap[b['id']!];

    if (aPos != null && bPos != null) {
      return aPos.compareTo(bPos);
    } else if (aPos != null && bPos == null) {
      return -1;
    } else if (aPos == null && bPos != null) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  });

  data.forEach((element) => print(element['id']));
  // 1000
  // 1
  // 1
  // 10
  // 2
  // 10
}
```

Comment: That was exactly what i was looking for, thank man